# How to check the presence of a string in the database and in cases of true and false to execute SQL commands

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I need some help.

I want to check `SIMPLE_TABLE` for a string where the `username` column contain `Ben` and in true case execute this command:

```
UPDATE `SIMPLE_TABLE` SET `number` = `number` + 3 WHERE username LIKE "Ben"
```

And in false (if the string doesn't exist) case I want execute other command:

```
INSERT INTO `SIMPLE_TABLE` (username, number) VALUES ('Ben', '3');
```

I tried to do this in a such way, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM SIMPLE_TABLE 
WHERE username='Ben';
BEGIN
    UPDATE `SIMPLE_TABLE` SET `number` = `number` + 3 WHERE username LIKE "Ben"
END

ELSE
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO SIMPLE_TABLE (username, number) VALUES ('Ben', '3')
END
```

How can I do that? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a unique index and `on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT INTO `SIMPLE_TABLE` (username, number)
    VALUES ('Ben', 3)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number = number + VALUES(number);
```

For this to work you need a unique index on `username`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_simple_table_username ON SIMPLE_TABLE(username);
```

It will also work if `username` is declared as the primary key.

Note:  `number` is -- presumably -- a number.  Keep the types consistent, which is why I removed the quotes around `3`.

Answer (score 0):

**INSERT INTO `TABLE_NAME` (column1, column2)**
    VALUES ('username', value_of_passd)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number = number + VALUES(number);

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Answers without an explanation, are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).